# Issue with Npgsql and .net core web app on Centos

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, centos7, npgsql

We have the following environment:

- asp.net core app (.net core 1.1),
- Postgre 9.3.5,
- ef 7 (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.2 / Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 1.1.0 - it uses Npgsql 3.1.9 ).
- The connection string is: "User ID=db_user;Password=db_pass;Host=db_host;Port=5432;Database=db_name;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=10;Keepalive=1;Connection Timeout=15;Command Timeout=30"

From time to time the application stop responsing to any requests (those requests that use database). After 15 minutes we get an exception:
**Npgsql.NpgsqlException (Exception while reading from stream)** 
(Full exception text see below).

After that exception any other requests show the same behaviour.

Maybe there are some issues with the network but the interesting thing is that when the pooling is disabled then we have no such kind of issues except connection timeouts which happen sometimes but they don’t take so long (they occur after 15 SECONDS not 15 MINUTES connection started as expected by default).

Any idea why when the pooling is enabled the connection is broken after 15 MINUTES? Who might be that guy that establishes that time – 15 minutes and why the connection is not broken after 15 seconds of connection timeout or 30 seconds of command timeout as it defined in the connection string.

We can also provide any additional information if needed.

```
"Exception" : {
        "Type" : "Npgsql.NpgsqlException",
        "Message" : "Exception while reading from stream",
        "StackTrace" : "   at Npgsql.ReadBuffer.<Ensure>d__27.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<DoReadMessage>d__148.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadPrependedMessages>d__150.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>d__147.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadExpecting>d__154`1.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<NextResult>d__31.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<NextResultAsync>d__30.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<Execute>d__70.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteDbDataReader>d__91.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>d__89.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__26.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable.AsyncEnumerator.<BufferlessMoveNext>d__9.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable.AsyncEnumerator.<MoveNext>d__8.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.SelectAsyncEnumerable`2.SelectAsyncEnumerator.<MoveNext>d__4.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.<_SingleOrDefault>d__123`1.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<MoveNext>d__3.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at RussianPost.ANM.GoodsService.ApplicationServices.Impl.GoodsSearcher.<SearchAsync>d__24.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at RussianPost.ANM.GoodsService.UI.Controllers.v1.GoodsController.<GetByType>d__2.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__27.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__25.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>d__24.MoveNext()",
        "InnerException" : {
            "Type" : "System.IO.IOException",
            "Message" : "Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection timed out.",
            "StackTrace" : "   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Npgsql.ReadBuffer.<Ensure>d__27.MoveNext()",
            "InnerException" : {
                "Type" : "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException",
                "Message" : "Connection timed out",
                "StackTrace" : "   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\n   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)",
                "InnerException" : null,
                "InnerExceptions" : null
            },
            "InnerExceptions" : null
        },
        "InnerExceptions" : null
    },
```

There are no any deadlocks in the DB logs and our DB is not highly loaded and queries are simple enough. Most of the queries are INSERT of one record and another portion is SELECT. We have 6 web services with 6 dedicated DBs.

We are tried exclude EF from the code and read the data with DataReader.
The same exception occurs after dataReader is started in 15 minutes:

```
"StackTrace" : "   at Npgsql.ReadBuffer.<EnsureAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<DoReadMessageAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessageWithPrependedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadExpectingAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<NextResultInternalAsync>d__1.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<NextResultAsync>d__47.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteDbDataReaderInternalAsync>d__4.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>d__99.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at RussianPost.ANM.CashTransactionsService.ApplicationServices.Impl.NoEfTransactionSearcherDataSource.<GetAlreadyRegisteredTransactionInfo>d__7.MoveNext() in E:\\Work\\CashTransactionsService\\src\\RussianPost.ANM.CashTransactionsService.ApplicationServices.Impl\\NoEfTransactionSearcherDataSource.cs:line 162\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at RussianPost.ANM.CashTransactionsService.ApplicationServices.Impl.TransactionSearcher.<SearchAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in E:\\Work\\CashTransactionsService\\src\\RussianPost.ANM.CashTransactionsService.ApplicationServices.Impl\\TransactionSearcher.cs:line 61\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at RussianPost.ANM.CashTransactionsService.UI.Controllers.v1.SearchTransactionsController.<Search>d__3.MoveNext() in E:\\Work\\CashTransactionsService\\src\\RussianPost.ANM.CashTransactionsService.UI\\Controllers\\v1\\SearchTransactionsController.cs:line 76",
        "InnerException" : {
            "Type" : "System.IO.IOException",
            "Message" : "Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection timed out.",
            "StackTrace" : "   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\n   at Npgsql.ReadBuffer.<EnsureAsync>d__0.MoveNext()",
            "InnerException" : {
                "Type" : "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException",
                "Message" : "Connection timed out",
                "StackTrace" : "   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\n   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)",
                "InnerException" : null,
                "InnerExceptions" : null
            },
            "InnerExceptions" : null
        },
```

Comment: You may want to try turning on keepalive (http://www.npgsql.org/doc/keepalive.html), in case some network device is dropping your connection due to inactivity.

Comment: Github issue: https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/241

Comment: Keepalive is set (Keepalive=1;). See the connection string from my post above.

Comment: In addition, since TcpKeepAlive is supported only for Windows, we changed tcp_keepalive_time for our CentOs (sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 60).

But it did not help :(

Comment: Sorry, didn't take a close enough look at your connection string... There's no need for TCP keepalives if you can use regular keepalives - the latter are superior in general.

Comment: Your exception stack clearly shows the timeout occurs as Npgsql is waiting for a response on a query you sent. Is there any chance your query really is very long? This can sometimes happen as a result of a deadlock on the PostgreSQL side (i.e. you have another query locking the same rows for update). You can take a look at your PostgreSQL logs (and increase verbosity) to try to understand which queries are being sent/processed simultaneously.

Comment: Topic updated with additional info.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly would cause the 15 minutes delay, but if you're getting occasional connection timeouts after 15 seconds (after turning off pooling) I'd definitely concentrate on finding the cause for that - either your network is causing issues, or your database server is extremely overloaded/misconfigured, or something similar. If you fix that, chances are that the original error may go away as well.